# Streaming music on a Mac

Tags: mac

I have a favorite Internet Radio station I like to listen to at www.bluefm.net. I recently started using a Mac. How to I listen to this using my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use iTunes to play the stream. Go to Advanced > Open Audio Stream... and paste the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VLC](http://videolan.org) to play the streams at http://ww.bluefm.net.

go to **Media** > **Open Network Stream** and paste the server URL

Comment: where is "media?" Sorry, I'm a brand new Mac user; just made the switch from using a PC :-)

Comment: **Media** refers to one of the top level menus you should find in the menu bar when VLC is running.  On a mac it may just be the **VLC** menu, sorry I don't have access to Mac right now to verify, but I'm pretty sure that's the menu structure.